# Put different rows from file in one column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, file

I have a file which has different rows and I want to put all the values in a table in postgres in one column.

My file is like that:

```
Houses   Houses                                                             
Palace                                                                  
Clock                                                                   
Bus  Clock   Sky     Street  Street  Tower                                              
bell     clock   faced   face    sun     tower                                              
stage    underground                                                                
palace   Palace  river
```

and I want to have a table with just one column as tag ant put everything in there! Like this:

```
Houses
Houses
Palace
Clock
Bus
```

Comment: I searched alot, but i couldn't find the answer; since I do not access ant Ide to code that!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in bash from the command line:

```
psql -qtAc "CREATE TABLE my_table (word text);"
for word in $(<my_file); do psql -qtAc "INSERT INTO my_table(word) VALUES ('$word');"; done
```

assuming of course that every word in the file is an entry in the table